# Ruby hash string with dates

Tags: ruby

Im working on a birthday widget, that shows the name of the person who is the closest to have his birthday.

I currently have the following code;

```
<% 
def closest_birthdate(birthdates) 
 sorted_dates = birthdates.sort_by do |_, value| 
  (DateTime.parse(value) - DateTime.now).abs
 end 
 name, birthday = sorted_dates.first 
 "#{name} has his birthday on #{Date.parse(birthday).strftime('%m-%d')}"
end 
%>

<% hash = { 'Bart' =>     '2017-12-06', 
            'Thomas' =>   '2017-10-06',
            'William' =>  '2018-09-05',} %> 
<%= closest_birthdate(hash) %>
```

It returns the following:

```
Thomas has his birthday on 10-06
```

Now, after his birthday, I have to change the year from 2017 to 2018. 
The dates with names are currently stored as strings.

1. How can I change the strings to dates?
2. How can I use their actual birth dates so I dont have to change the year from 2017 to 2018 everytime they had their birthday?

Comment: Regarding 1) use `Date.new(2017, 12, 6)` instead of `'2017-12-06'`. Regarding 2) what to you mean by "actual birth date", could you give an example?

Comment: @Stefan the year they are born, like 1978.

Comment: Then it would be `{ 'Thomas' => Date.new(1978, 10, 6) }`.

Comment: @Stefan getting error; no implicit conversion of Date into String

Comment: You should have mentioned that [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46562753/477037) wrote the above code for you! Because of the code (using `sort_by` and array decomposition), I was under the impression that you have some Ruby knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Storing dates

A [`Date`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) instance can be created via [`Date::new`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-new):

```
require 'date'

birthdate = Date.new(1978, 12, 6)
#=> #<Date: 1978-12-06 ...>
```

#### Calculating the next birthday

The next or upcoming birthday for the above birthdate is 2017-12-06, so we have to combine today's year and the birthdate's month and day:

```
today = Date.today
#=> #<Date: 2017-10-06 ...>

next_birthday = Date.new(today.year, birthdate.month, birthdate.day)
#=> #<Date: 2017-12-06 ...>
```

What happens if the birthday already occurred this year?

```
birthdate = Date.new(1985, 9, 5)
#=> #<Date: 1985-12-06 ...>

next_birthday = Date.new(today.year, birthdate.month, birthdate.day)
#=> #<Date: 2017-09-05 ...>
```

To actually get the *next* birthday, we have to add a year in that case: (i.e. if `next_birthday` happens to be before today)

```
next_birthday = next_birthday.next_year if next_birthday < today
#=> #<Date: 2018-09-05 ...>
```

#### Finding the closest birthday

Let's move the above calculation into a method:

```
def next_birthday(birthdate, today = Date.today)
  date = Date.new(today.year, birthdate.month, birthdate.day)
  date < today ? date.next_year : date
end
```

To find the closest (upcoming) birthday, we can either use `sort_by` and `first`:

```
hash = {
  'Bart'    => Date.new(1978, 12, 6), 
  'Thomas'  => Date.new(1981, 10, 6),
  'William' => Date.new(1985, 9, 5)
}

hash.sort_by { |_name, birthdate| next_birthday(birthdate) }
#=> [
#  ["Thomas", #<Date: 1981-10-06 ...>],
#  ["Bart", #<Date: 1978-12-06 ...>],
#  ["William", #<Date: 1985-09-05 ...>]
# ]

hash.sort_by { |_name, birthdate| next_birthday(birthdate) }.first
#=> ["Thomas", #<Date: 1981-10-06 ...>]
```

or [`min_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-min_by):

```
hash.min_by { |_name, birthdate| next_birthday(birthdate) }
#=> ["Thomas", #<Date: 1981-10-06 ...>]
```

#### Generating output

```
name, birthdate = hash.min_by { |_name, birthdate| next_birthday(birthdate) }

puts "#{name}'s birthday is on #{birthdate.strftime('%m-%d')}"
# Thomas's birthday is on 10-06
```

We could also add the age:

```
age = next_birthday(birthdate).year - birthdate.year
#=> 36

puts "#{name} is turning #{age} on #{birthdate.strftime('%m-%d')}"
# Thomas is turning 36 on 10-06
```

#### Edge case

February 29 only occurs on leap years:

```
Date.new(1984, 2, 29)
#=> #<Date: 1984-02-29 ...>
```

Attempting to create a February 29 on a non-leap year results in an error:

```
Date.new(2017, 2, 29)
#=> ArgumentError: invalid date
```

You could remove those dates or adjust them unless today's year is [`leap?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-leap-3F) (to Feb 28 or Mar 1).

Comment: @Doeple how do you run that code? BTW you either need `sort_by` + `first` or `min_by`, not both. (and you don't have to copy the comments into your code)

Comment: @Doeple Page? Are you using a web framework like Rails or Sinatra?

Comment: @Doeple you probably have to use `<%= "#{name} is turning #{age} on #{birthdate.strftime('%m-%d')}" %>` then, just like in your code.

Comment: @Doeple you have to put the first part of the code into `<% ... %>` and the last line (the one generating output) into `<%= ... %>` (note the `=`). Try to solve such kind of problems yourself before asking for help. Just compare your code to my code. What is different? What is missing? It's not that hard :-)

Comment: @Doeple I've included a link to the documentation for `min_by` in my answer.

Comment: To return the second upcoming date, I should use hash.min_by(2) right? @Stefan

Comment: @Doeple you already [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642643/getting-the-second-upcoming-date-from-date-hash), didn't you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard object as a (birth)day without specification of the year. So you should just save an array of month and day of month. And it is much better to save them as integers rather than strings.

```
hash = {
  'Bart' => [12, 6],
  'Thomas' => [10, 6],
  'William' => [9, 5],
}
```

To convert them to a date with a year specification (let's say `year = 2018`), do like this:

```
require "date"
date = Date.new(year, *hash['Bart']) rescue nil
```

---

Implementing it fully would be like this:

```
require "date"

def closest_birthdate(birthdates)
  year, month, day = Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day
  name, (m, d) =
    birthdates
    .sort_by(&:last)
    .bsearch{|_, (m, d)| month <= m and day < d}
  return unless Date.new(year, m, d) rescue nil
  "#{name} has his birthday on #{year}-#{m}-#{d}"
end

closest_birthdate(hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you don't want to change the structure:

```
<% 
def closest_birthdate(birthdates) 
 sorted_dates = birthdates.sort_by do |_, value| 
  array = value.split("-") # you got something like this [2017, 12, 06]
  (DateTime.parse("#{DateTime.now.year}-#{array[1]}-#{array[2]}") - DateTime.now).abs
 end 
 name, birthday = sorted_dates.first 
 "#{name} has his birthday on #{Date.parse(birthday).strftime('%m-%d')}"
end 
%>

<% hash = { 'Bart' =>     '1978-12-06', 
            'Thomas' =>   '1972-10-06',
            'William' =>  '1992-09-05',} %> 
<%= closest_birthdate(hash) %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: With this, we don't need to care about the `year they are born`. We can use the days and months to find the closest birthday.

Comment: What is that `'the_year_you_want-'` prefix? Does the OP has to fill in a specific year?

Comment: You can replace `the_year_you_want` with the year you want like 1978, ... just try :D

Comment: @sawa why you think it does not solve problem 2 - OP want to use actual birthdays. I sure this solved both 2. and just change 2 lines of codes.

Comment: @thanhnha1103 oh I see :-) I think your code would be clearer with actual years.